# Android app send email confirmation no sender name

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I try to send confirmation email for a user who log in using facebook login. I successfully sent the email but there's no sender name when I open the email in email app. It's just blank. I want may be the name of the sender (my app name) or may be just the email such noreply@mydomain.com

I changed the codes and my hosting email settings with alternatives but no success in the last 2 days.

in LoginActivity on success:

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("noreply@mydomain.com","thepassword");
sender.sendMail(
name + ", Login into theappname",
"Hi, "+name+". You've just signed in to the app.",
"noreply@mydomain.com",
emailRecipient);
```

and in GMailSender class:

```
public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "mail.mydomain.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(_multipart);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

I want to show the sender name (myAppName) or just email address (noreply@mydomain.com). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you want to use the setFrom method, not the setSender method.  And you want to use the [InternetAddress constructor that takes an email address and a "personal name"](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Finally, you may want to fix any of these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: Hi Bill, great thank you for the answer. I 'm not sure why i missed that part. I change the setSender to setFrom and it works now. Regards